# Integrate values over time to get position in the unity c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two values X and Y, that are the values returned by (Thumbstick)joystick which is connected to Arduino. 
Now, I have to perform integration(Maths) on these values to return me the cursor position.

I have checked Mathf API in unity, but not sure how to use it. Or is there any other framework that does it the same.

speed(t) = value(t) - this is the value from arduino

cursor(t) = integrate speed(t) over time

Comment: The `x` and `y` values returned by the joystick are probably just intensities and not actual cursor positions, so your going to be using that as an offset to the current cursor position as such for both axes (pseudo code): `mousePosition.x += thumbstick.x * Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: can i use public static float Clamp(float value, float min, float max); to return me the values ?

Comment: @KhushalGupta Do you know what `Clamp` does? How do you think it solves this problem?

Comment: Clamp will return me the values within the limits I provide in the parameter. I seriously don't know.

Comment: Because I am looking to perform velocity control in my thumbstick which is connected via arduino. So, the values that I will get after integrating these values  from arduino, I can get the cursor position, to set in my unity scene, and that would have velocity control.

Comment: It sounds like you want to set the system cursor's position. Is that right? That will require you to write code to handle how to do that in specific platforms such as Windows. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: and whats wrong with just doing what I wrote? you can even add a speed variable in there: `mousePosition.x += thumbstick.x * Time.deltaTime * speed;`. Before asking about alternatives, please tell me whats wrong with this.

Comment: @Ruzihm that's correct. I am working in unity, C# script.

Comment: @maksymiuk Hi, I am not sure about the results of the code. But I am like kinda more interested in doing something like this. https://www.extremeoptimization.com/QuickStart/CSharp/BasicIntegration.aspx

Comment: @maksymiuk `Input.mousePosition` is read-only, so you would have to copy it and then you'll only be modifying a copy of the vector that represents the mouse's current position.

Comment: @Ruzihm which is why i didn't specify `Input.mousePosition` but i only put `mousePosition` as if it were a local variable.

Comment: @maksymiuk Asker wants to modify the position of the system cursor, not simply modify a copy of it.

Comment: @Ruzihm all he specified is he wants to be 'returned a cursor position' as if he already has a plan on what to do with the *position*. Altering the system cursor is not necessarily a desirable means when working in Unity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate any kind of integrals. Instead, on each update, multiply `Time.deltaTime` with the value from arduino that frame to get the cursor delta for that frame.

For a windows release, you can use the win32 API to set the mouse position accordingly. (per [this answer](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1476158/view.html) by zachwuzhere on the Unity QA site)

Altogether, it might look like this:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);

private float horizontalFromArduino;
private float verticalFromArduino;

public float sensitivity;

void Update() 
{
    float newXPos = Input.mousePosition.x + horizontalFromArduino * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    newXPos = Mathf.Clamp(0,Screen.width);
    float newYPos = Input.mousePosition.y + verticalFromArduino * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    newYPos = Mathf.Clamp(0,Screen.height);

    // y=0 is top of screen in windows coordinates, so we subtract newYPos from Screen.height
    SetCursorPos(newXPos, Screen.height - newYPos); 
}
```

Comment: what would be the value in sensitivity ? Is this like optional or required. ?

Comment: @KhushalGupta definitely something that isn't zero, probably something between 0 and infinity. I have no idea what kind of numbers your arduino controller outputs.

Comment: > on each update, multiply Time.deltaTime with the value from arduino that frame
That would be exactly what an integral is :) (or at least an approximation of one)

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for your code snippet, it works for me.

Comment: @KhushalGupta Glad to hear it. If you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the grey checkmark next to it, it would give me some reputation points and help other people with similar problems find it in the future!

Comment: @Ruzihm already did it but it gives me some message like - "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Thanks! That's because you aren't allowed to vote until you have enough reputation. However, you can always click the checkmark to accept an answer on your own question. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)